# Linux Mint chooses random MAC address on bootup

Tags: linux-mint, network-adapter, mac-address

Every time I start a machine with Linux Mint 14 installed, the Ethernet NIC chooses a random MAC address to use. Is there a way to disable that behavior?

Comment: This usually happens because the physical mac is no longer in the firmware.  Can you boot another OS to confirm it isn't mint specifically causing it?

Comment: check to make sure you don't have the package 'macchanger' installed.

Comment: I do not have macchanger installed.

Comment: @Paul I don't have access to Windows. Would another Linux distribution (Fedora) work?

Comment: Yeah,I would try any livecd. Check it against the real Mac (there should be a sticker on the nic or on the machine somewhere for integrated cards)

Comment: @Paul No sticker for the MAC on the laptop. Fedora chooses a random MAC as well on each bootup (tried twice). I tried [link]http://goo.gl/wgRPP[/link] and now the machine won't get an IP without running `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround, I suspect the card is faulty and has lost its mac address in firmware.

First install macchanger

```
sudo apt-get install macchanger
```

Put a script in `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d` containing

```
macchanger eth0 -m 00:16:3e:11:11:18
```

This will change the mac of eth0 prior to bringing it up.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. [Screenshot](http://s22.postimg.org/zdaheen1d/Capture.png)

Comment: If you run the script as root does it work from the command line?  You may need to put the path to macchanger into the script, and `chmod +x` it.

Comment: Running it as root works. I tried [these](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/336736/comments/32) instructions as well and it gets the correct MAC address, but fails to obtain an IP address.